# Doctrine2 using Native Query to join an unmapped Entity

Tags: symfony, doctrine-orm

I have two Entities: Workorder, and Photo. Photo is storing an image BLOB in each row. I need to be able to grab the latest photo in the Workorder, without manualling setting it for each Workorder result. I originally set up a OneToOne relationship in the Workorder to the Photo field, which I later with the QueryBuilder with a "WITH" clause to get the latest photo. This worked fine for that use case, however it seems that if I select a Photo and let the Workorder be joined (Photo has a ManyToOne with Workorder), then the Workorder went ahead and grabbed every Photo which was related. Considering the Photo stores a BLOB, that got expensive really fast.

I really only needed to join the latest Photo for one specific use case, but it needs to be part of the Workorder object. I thought that Native Queries would help me here, as I thought I would be able to map the joined object into a Workorder field, but I can't seem to make that work, or find any resources on this particular problem.

I have a field called `$latest_photo` in Workorder, but I have no mapping for it. I thought I would be able to map the joined Photo object into this field. Is this possible, or am I reading it wrong?

```
$rsm->addEntityResult('WorkOrder', 't0');
$rsm->addJoinedEntityResult('Photo', 't1', 't0', 'latest_photo');
```

This is what I've tried, but I just get a Hydrate error saying that "index latest_photo doesn't exist".

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you try [Extra Lazy Associations](https://doctrine-orm.readthedocs.org/en/latest/tutorials/extra-lazy-associations.html) before going with native queries?

Comment: I tried, but it's still trying to JOIN all of the Photo's. It didn't really seem to do anything.